# Do I need to worry about packed primops in GHC?

Tags: performance, haskell

There is an additional (internal) layer in GHC which just wraps the primitive known to meet the `Int` abstraction requirements.

```
data {-# CTYPE "HsInt" #-} Int = I# Int#
```

As a GHC user, am I ever expected to make use of it other than understanding that STG will generate code like `-# 1#`?

Are there any known cases where GHC generates code doing the wrapping? If so, why?

Comment: Some time ago I've seen an example where using prim-ops on `Int#` instead of `Int` was used to eliminate a bottleneck. Otherwise, I don't think you should care, especially with `UNPACK`/`-funbox-strict-fields`.

Comment: If you need to use primops it's probably from having to heavily optimize a routine to an excessive point.  The vast majority of people never run into these issues in any language, Haskell included.